# Disabling Power button on keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, button-remapping

My keyboard has a Power button that when pressed turns off the machine. I sometimes press it by accident, and lose everything I was doing in adition to having to wait for the PC to turn off and then turn it on again.

How can I disable this button in Windows XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Control Panel** → **Switch to Classic View** → **Power Options** → **Advanced** tab. There you can select what the power buttons (Power, Sleep, etc.) should do when pressed:

- Shut down
- Do nothing (this solves your problem)
- Ask me what do do.

This will also affect the physical power button on your computer, though.

[image: Power Options Properties]

Comment: Better than this is to set it to ask what to do.  This way he has an escape route if the button is pressed by accident, but can still use the button on purpose as well.

Comment: I prefer not to be asked. Confirmations don't help for potentially dangerous operations. Consult Raskin, Cooper, &c. on that :-)

Comment: I do read the dialog boxes unlike a lot of people, so this is probably the best thing to do. I'll try to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try looking into [**AutoHotKey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/). The software is excellent and I use it for this exact purpose. The software is free and consumes almost nothing in resources.

I remapped the Sleep Key (in my case) to do absolutely nothing, and it's trivial to do yourself.

Just open up the script in notepad

1. Open up the script you're using in notepad.
2. Try entering `Sleep::`

If this doesn't disable it - then there a couple more steps you need to take.

1. Install a keyboard hook by entering `#InstallKeybdHook`
2. Find out what key it is by looking at the key history in the main window.
3. Enter `KEY::` where KEY is the key's name.

Comment: [**SharpKeys**](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) can also be used to remap a key to another key or do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Pop it off with screwdriver. Works with any OS.

Comment: Sure, because people love to tear apart their keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Tweak UI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) and look under the Explorer > Command Keys section for a key assignment.

Comment: The link you have provided above no longer works.