# Power button behavior on Dell XPS

Tags: power

I just reinstalled Windows XP on my Dell XPS M1710 laptop. Now whenever I (accidentally) hit the power button the machine shuts down without warning; previously you had to hold it for a few seconds before it shut down.

Does anyone know how I can restore the original behavior?

<sub>There is already [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/55833/disabling-power-button-on-keyboard) on SU, but there's no talk about the delay there, just changing the button's function.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hold-for-4-seconds shutdown is usually motherboard driven (which is why it works at any time and even if your OS completely locks).

My guess is that the power button was configured to do nothing previously, and by reinstalling Windows it has defaulted to powering down the machines. As this is now a Windows driven action there is no delay.

Have a look in the power profile settings of your machine, you probably need to just change the behaviour of your power button to be able to restore your previous configuration.

To do this, from `Control Panel` access `Power Options`.
Look in `Properties` then `Advanced`.
Under `Power Buttons`, select whichever option is most suited to your needs.

Comment: Accepted as answer for the vital clue "motherboard driven". I changed the behavior to "do nothing" and the delayed shut-down is back. Thanks a million!

Comment: @steven - just spotted you said "reinstalled XP" in the question, otherwise I'd off been more precise with instructions and less vauge with the "possibly reasons it has happened". Oh well, it solved your problem anyway, but I might tweak the answer a little so it's more valid. [Edit: answer tweaked]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Dell Controlpoint System Manager application installed? It should contain power management features where it's possible to set the power button behaviour.

On a "vanilla" Windows XP, try looking in Control Panel->Power Options (see [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/maintain/powermgmt.mspx), step 6)