# Delay action for holding power button

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, power

So basically what happened is that sometimes accidentally press power button and it shuts down my PC. I went to Power options and pressed "Change what the power buttons do" and I can only change action, but not modify it. I want to set delay for holding power button, for example if I hold it for 3 seconds, my system will shut down, instead of instantly like now. Thank in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power button behavior on Dell XPS](http://superuser.com/questions/181296/power-button-behavior-on-dell-xps)

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

Keep in mind that holding the powerbutton for 5 seconds instantly shuts down the computer without first closing down. This is a hardware action, not a software action.

The only thing you can do is change it to `Do nothing`.

Shutting down your pc can still be done through the start menu, and you can create a shortcut to a script that shuts down the computer. This script could have an optional 5 second countdown to abort it.

Alternatively, there is software available that prevents a shutdown. If you accidentally press the powerbutton, that software will cause the computer to give you the message: `The computer cannot be shutdown because "prevent shutdown` is preventing it. Do you want to force shutdown or cancel? With a time out that will cancel the shutdown.

You can also change the powerbutton action to hibernate. If you then accidentally press it, it'll put the pc in hibernation and you can continue to work by pressing it once more. It just creates an inconvenient delay of about 30 seconds for the whole routine.

Comment: If holding down the power button for 5 seconds is a hardware action then how can making a change in software affect it?

Comment: Have the opposite problem. I need to hold the button for several seconds before it shuts down (and it does actually _shut down;_ it's no hard kill), but want it instant. No BIOS settings found about it either :-\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Acer Switch Alpha which is a tablet/laptop hybrid.  When I'm using it as a tablet it's very easy to accidently touch the power button and turn it off.

I changed both "When I press power button" and "When I press sleep button" to "Do Nothing" and don't have any issues now.  I turn the computer off via the start menu, or if it's bugging out with a long hold.