# How can I stop my keyboard's Power button from shutting down my PC without disabling my laptop's Power button?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard, power

I've got a Logitech K270 keyboard which, as shown in the image below, has a little "power" button on top of the row of F keys (the next-to-last key to the right on the top row). This is part of the keyboard's *hotkeys*. I've accidentally pressed this button and turned my PC off a couple of times, and it can be super frustrating.

How can I disable the keyboard's power button?

According to [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/55833/disabling-power-button-on-keyboard), I can use the Control Panel (`Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings`) to change what happens when I press the power button or close the laptop lid. However, there's a big problem here. If I use this approach, it also disables the **laptop's** power button. But I still want the power button **on the laptop** to shut down my PC!!!

I also tried using AutoHotKey, but it's KeyHook/KeyListener was unable to pick up on the keypress for the keyboard's power button, so I couldn't remap it.

Another solution would be to physically remove the power key from my keyboard. But I'd like to keep my keyboard intact, even if that particular key is utterly useless to me.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

[image: Logitech K270 hotkeys and power button]

Comment: perhaps the dumbest "feature" ever added.  why no "shoot myself" key?

Comment: I've seen some keyboards with the power/sleep button right in the delete/home/end/pageup/pagedown group which is even worse than this

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good answer, although its not a software hack (your question did not actually say it needs to be software).  Its OS agnostic as well..

I used a small square of cardboard (cut from a correlated cardboard box lid) and gently wedged it in the top of the key.  Easy enough to remove, and hardly visible - especially if I spent a few minutes taking more care with the cutting/sizing, or using grey/black board.   Took way longer to photograph and upload then make and install!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is downloading and installing [**Logitech Options**](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893) or the older [**SetPoint**](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025141274), both can be used to customize keyboards.

Once installed, you should be able go to the keyboard tab and change the PC power button to "do nothing" (or you can assign it to another function / keystroke).

Comment: [**SharpKeys**](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) can also be used to remap a key to another key or do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue as well on my keyboard. I saw a solution to this a few years ago that might work for you as well. (I can't find it otherwise I would link it here.)

**Follow these steps**:

- Go to Device Manager.
- Find the "Human Interface Devices" list
- Find the "HID-compliant system controller"
- Disable it

That should do it.
It stops the keyboard button from shutting down your pc.

If you have more than one HID-compliant system controller, the other might be from your mouse. Find the one from your keyboard to disable it. or disable both of them since it won't affect the actual power button on the computer.

Hope this helps if you are still using the keyboard.